# How to check the characters of one column match another column using SQL

Tags: sql

`Column Name: Name`

**Values:**

```
1.Praveen kumar

2.Praveen
```

In the same column If the first word is same in another row then I need a query to extract those names and display them.

column name: ename

```
        praveen kumar
        praveen
        praveen international
```

In this case 1st row should be compared with 2nd row i.e `praveen kumar` with `praveen` and has to write the first word as it is matching, and the same process with all other names.

The query that I tried:

```
SELECT
        e1.ename
        e2.ename
    FROM emp as e1,emp as e2
    WHERE
        e1.ename<e2.ename
        and substring(e1.ename,1,7) = substring(e2.ename,1,7)
```

...but if I need to compare many names of such kind in a database without specifying the length of characters to compare. If the first word matches with the other field the I need those names.

Comment: Good, now show us what you've tried so far and where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: select e1.ename,e2.ename from emp as e1,emp as e2 where e1.ename<e2.ename and substring(e1.ename,1,7)=substring(e2.ename,1,7)...but if i need to compare many names of such kind in a database without specifying the length of characters to compare..if the first word matches with the other field the i need those names

Comment: Please update (edit) your question instead of put it in the comment.

Comment: `without specifying the length` this would then require you to either write a custom function that recognizes word boundaries (whitespaces, interpunctuation) and gets you the first word of a given varchar, or use some regex-stuff (but that would largely depend on what sqldbms you are using, whether you get it out of the box)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT id
          ,CASE
               WHEN ename not like '% %' THEN ename -- single word
               ELSE Left(ename, Patindex('% %', ename) - 1) -- first word
           END AS first_word
           ,ename
      FROM emp
)
SELECT DISTINCT complete.ename
  FROM a AS first
       JOIN a as complete
            ON first.first = complete.first
           AND first.id <> complete.id -- avoid a row matching itself
```

This assumes name parts are separated by space characters.

The `WITH` clause handles the extraction of the first word, it assumes name parts are separated by space characters. It might have to be adapted if the rules are different. Then there is a join of the table with itself on the first word.

Comment: this does `NOT` compare the first word inside of `col1` against `col2` but only whether `col1` begins with the contents of `col2`

Comment: @DrCopyPaste My answer was posted when the question was still very different from the current one. I edited it completely to match the current query.

Comment: hm i am not sure that covers what the OP asked for since you constrain it to only check against those values that do not contain any space, but what about the values containing multiple words that you want to compare only the first word of (and you do not get that word from another column were it is the only string contained within)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste You are right, after re-reading the question, I edited the statement.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is way more complicated than it needs to be, but this is what I have come up with:

Essentially I used a custom function described [here](http://madprops.org/blog/t-sql-to-split-a-varchar-into-words/) that splits a varchar into words.
(As you look closely this is not perfect as it only respects space and comma, but it could be easily extended or replaced by something more complex)

Then in the final select it can be used to get all words from all selected rows in the source set, join that to a set of all values from the target set you want to compare against, but only where the values indeed begin with the same string, then you join those values from the target set again to all extracted words from that and compare for equality and position and at the last step filter those out where it does not match.

[Fiddle to try out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c91d2/13)

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitWords(@text varchar(8000))
   RETURNS @words TABLE (
      pos smallint primary key,
      value varchar(8000)
   )
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE
      @pos smallint,
      @i smallint,
      @j smallint,
      @s varchar(8000)

   SET @pos = 1
   WHILE @pos <= LEN(@text) 
   BEGIN 
      SET @i = CHARINDEX(' ', @text, @pos)
      SET @j = CHARINDEX(',', @text, @pos)
      IF @i > 0 OR @j > 0
      BEGIN
         IF @i = 0 OR (@j > 0 AND @j < @i)
            SET @i = @j

         IF @i > @pos
         BEGIN
            -- @i now holds the earliest delimiter in the string
            SET @s = SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, @i - @pos)

            INSERT INTO @words
            VALUES (@pos, @s)
         END 
         SET @pos = @i + 1

         WHILE @pos < LEN(@text) 
            AND SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, 1) IN (' ', ',')
            SET @pos = @pos + 1
      END 
      ELSE 
      BEGIN 
         INSERT INTO @words 
         VALUES (@pos, SUBSTRING(@text, @pos, LEN(@text) - @pos + 1))

         SET @pos = LEN(@text) + 1
      END 
   END 
   RETURN
END

GO

CREATE TABLE SampleSourceValues(ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), Value VARCHAR(127))
INSERT INTO SampleSourceValues (Value)
  SELECT 'First Word'
  UNION
  SELECT 'Second Time'
  UNION
  SELECT 'Yet Another Word'

GO

CREATE TABLE SampleTargetMatches(ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), Value VARCHAR(127))
INSERT INTO SampleTargetMatches (Value)
  SELECT 'Firstmispelled Word'
  UNION
  SELECT 'Second Time'
  UNION
  SELECT 'Another Word'

SELECT
      --IncludedWords.pos,
      --IncludedWords.value,
      SampleTargetMatches.Value
    FROM SampleSourceValues --select from SampleSourceValues
    CROSS APPLY
    (
      SELECT
          pos,
          value
        FROM dbo.SplitWords(SampleSourceValues.Value)
    ) AS IncludedWords -- apply word splitting to each value from SampleSourceValues
    INNER JOIN SampleTargetMatches
      ON CHARINDEX(IncludedWords.value, SampleTargetMatches.Value) = 1 AND IncludedWords.pos = 1
      -- join rows from SampleTargetMatches that where Value starts with a word from IncludedWords that has pos = 1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
      SELECT
          pos,
          value
        FROM dbo.SplitWords(SampleTargetMatches.Value)
    ) AS IncludedWordsInTarget -- apply word splitting to each value from SampleTargetMatches
    WHERE IncludedWordsInTarget.value = IncludedWords.value AND IncludedWordsInTarget.pos = 1
```

In the results you can see that only the value `Second Time` gets retrieved as it is the only one where the first word matches exatly with the first word of the source values.

Comment: i guess its in T-Sql and i dont have any idea abt T-sql but will try to understand by checking out the syntax

Comment: @user3218342 yes this is t-sql-syntax (as you did not specify any dbms) but AFAIK only `GO` (for SQLSMS) and `CHARINDEX` are tsql-specific you could easily split it into seperate queries (i.e. get rid of the `GO`) and substitute `CHARINDEX` with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and that should also do it for mysql, not sure about `SUBSTRING` though, but surely there is an equivalent too ;)

Comment: Aw, I am sorry, I just read up on that a little bit, it seems `MySQL` has no `APPLY` clause, I am not sure how to substitute it there, sorry about that.

Comment: @user3218342 it pretty sure is, but unfortunately I am not too familiar with oracle function declarations maybe someone can post a modified version of my fiddle? I try come back here later (when I get to rewrite it in oracle)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct t1.<Field_Name>,t2.<Field_Name> 
from <Table_name> t1 
inner join  <Table_name>  t2 on t1.<Field_Name> like t2.<Field_Name>+'%'
order by t2.<Field_Name>
```

Hope this will help you.....

Comment: this does `NOT` compare the first word inside of `t2.<Field_Name>` against `t1.<Field_Name>` but only whether `t2.<Field_Name>` is contained within `t1.<Field_Name>` regardless of whether it contains only one word

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want a descending order then use below :
    select ename from emp order by ename;

    if you want a distinct name then
    select distinct ename from emp order by ename;

    if you want a specific name wise search :
    select ename from emp where ename like 'praveen%' order by ename
```

Comment: can u suggest me if name is not mentioned then how to compare the words..Like praveen many other names may be there in the database so i need to extract them.

Comment: it's not not need to use where clause for compare, it's simple order by column.

Comment: @user3218342 take a look at my answer ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253211/how-to-check-the-character-of-one-filed-matches-with-another-using-sql/21256525#21256525